# Set value of duplicated fields from database

Tags: javascript, php

I have a fieldset that is cloned using clone() function, on the other hand I need to set some values of the cloned fields automatically from database, I don't know how to do it in my form since in my html I only have access to the original fieldset and not the cloned one, any ideas on how to do so ?

Here is my code :

```
<div class='placeholder'>
    <div id='template0' name='template0' class='template'>
        <p>
        <fieldset id='financement_actuel_pret' class='financement_actuel_pret'>
        <legend>Financement actuel:</legend>

            <div class='pp_div' style='text-align: center; font-size: 150%;'> Prêt Principale</div>
            <div id='choix_pret0' name='choix_pret0' class='div_choixpret' style='display : none'>
            <label class='ajout' for='choixpret'>Choix du prêt&nbsp;:</label>
            <select id='choixpret0' name='choixpret0'>\r\n
            <option value=''>* Sélectionnez *</option>\r\n
            <option value='conserve'".(($choixpret0=="conserve")? " selected='selected'" : NULL).">Conservé</option>\r\n
            <option value='rachete'".(($choixpret0=="rachete")? " selected='selected'" : NULL).">Racheté</option>\r\n
            </select>\r\n
            </div>
        </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Where **"$choixpretX"** is the value I get from the database for each field :

```
$choixpret0 = (strlen($tabStat{'choixpret0'})>0) ? utf8_encode($tabStat{'choixpret0'}) : "";
$choixpret1 = (strlen($tabStat{'choixpret1'})>0) ? utf8_encode($tabStat{'choixpret1'}) : "";
$choixpret2 = (strlen($tabStat{'choixpret2'})>0) ? utf8_encode($tabStat{'choixpret2'}) : "";
$choixpret3 = (strlen($tabStat{'choixpret3'})>0) ? utf8_encode($tabStat{'choixpret3'}) : "";
```

How can I say that for the next cloned fields the value would be for example  **$choixpret1=="conserve"** for the field where the cloned id would be "**choix_pret1**"

Comment: Perhaps you need to look at AJAX?

Comment: "in my html I only have access to the original fieldset and not the cloned one"...once you've cloned it you have access to the object representing the fields, even before you add it to the DOM. It's not clear what you mean - perhaps you're saying that you don't have access to it at the time when your PHP is generating the HTML? That is perfectly true. So if you need to fetch some extra data into these fields without refreshing the page, you need to make an AJAX request to the server, get the data, and update the cloned fields.

Comment: @Adyson this is exactly what I meant, thank you I will try to do discover AJAX, I have never used it before

Comment: No problem. AJAX is not too hard to use, once you get the idea. There are hundreds of tutorials, demos, examples, previous questions on sites like SO relating to AJAX, you should not have much trouble finding information

Answer (score 0):

Given that I don't seem to see your JS.
What I can suggest is when you do your clone - you send an ajax request to run your PHP script to fetch again the data and use the response you get to set your clone value.